# Depth of Tuple Tree Structure in Python

Tags: python

I want to make a recursive function, that measures the depth of a 
tuple tree structure in Python 2. It is an exercise in the course AI at MIT and I am not taking the course.

I start from left and add a zero to the leaves of the tree. If not a leaf I go down the tree until I reach a leaf. I max over the children and return the result to the parent. Recursion will give me the final result.

```
#input
ls0 = 'x'
ls1 = ('expt', 'x', 2)
ls2 = ('+', ('expt', 'x', 2), ('expt', 'y', 2))
ls4 = ('/', ('expt', 'x', 5), ('expt', ('-', ('expt', 'x', 2),1), ('/', 5, 2)))

#expected output
print(depth(ls4)) #expected output 4
print(depth(ls2)) #expected output 2
print(depth(ls1)) #expected output 1

#function definition
def depth(expr):
    a = []
    for j in range(len(expr)):
        if isinstance(expr,(list,tuple)) == 0:
            a.append(0)
            if len(a) == len(expr):
                return max(a)
        else:
            a.append(1 + depth(expr[j]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this simple recursive solution:

```
def depth(l):
    depths = [depth(item) for item in l if isinstance(item, tuple)]

    if len(depths) > 0:
        return 1 + max(depths)

    return 1

ls0 = ('x')
ls1 = ()
ls2 = ('expt', 'x', 2)
ls3 = ('+', ('expt', 'x', 2), ('expt', 'y', 2))
ls4 = ('/', ('expt', 'x', 5), ('expt', ('-', ('expt', 'x', 2),1), ('/', 5, 2)))

tuples = [ls0, ls1, ls2, ls3, ls4]
for tup in tuples:
    print(depth(tup))
```

Which Outputs:

```
1
1
1
2
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the recursive solution. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In your recursion function, use a counter to keep track of the current depth:

```
ls0 = 'x'
ls1 = ('expt', 'x', 2)
ls2 = ('+', ('expt', 'x', 2), ('expt', 'y', 2))
ls4 = ('/', ('expt', 'x', 5), ('expt', ('-', ('expt', 'x', 2),1), ('/', 5, 2)))
tree = [ls1, ls2, ls4]
def depth(b, count=0):
   if isinstance(b, str) or isinstance(b, int) or all(not isinstance(i, tuple) for i in b):
     yield count+1
   else:
     for i in b:
       for c in depth(i, count+1):
         yield c

final_results = [max(i) for i in list(map(list, list(map(depth, tree))))]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```